# Copied files manually. Dropbox wants to re-upload them all

Tags: sync, dropbox

I'm reinstalling Windows on a new hard drive, and copying everything across from the old one.  I have something like 100GB of photos synced to Dropbox, but it seemed silly to download them all off the internet when I could just copy them from the old drive.

That done, I reboot and now Dropbox announces that it's planning to sync these 145,000 files that changed "Just Now".

How do I convince it to look at its checksums and ignore them all?

Comment: Looking at the checksums is what it’s doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You will see it syncing 145,000. What Dropbox is doing is verifying that the file chunks match the file hash on the Dropbox servers. Dropbox doesn't know if these new files are identical, so it has to go through the process of scanning the entire file contents, getting a hash of it, and comparing it to that of the Dropbox servers. There is no way to get around this. If it ignores the checksums and your data is not identical, that will cause a lot of problems.